# WinForms TreeView Orientation

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, treeview

Is it possible to change the orientation of the Winforms TreeView control? I would like to navigate top-down-expand-left-to-right rather than then default top-down-expand-to-right. I have found a WPF solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx) but I can't seem to find a WinForms alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the basic Windows Tree Control.

You will need to write or acquire a custom/third party control to do it.

Answer (score 0):

See this article : http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.2/CLR2.0/html/WinTree_Displaying_WinTree_with_Columns_in_Grid_Style.html

The WinGrid control can be used like this.